# Resourse permission checker Liferay 7

Tags: permissions, liferay, action, liferay-7

I have my portlet with CRUD-operations (different bundles, services, etc.).

I want to implement custom actions in permission for this portlet.

I create `default.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<resource-action-mapping>
       <portlet-resource>
       <portlet-name>com.mypackage.MyPortlet</portlet-name>
          <permissions>
           <supports>
               <action-key>STACKOVERFLOW_ACTION</action-key>
           </supports>
           </permissions>
       </portlet-resource>
</resource-action-mapping>
```

And create `portlet.properties`:

```
include-and-override=portlet-ext.properties
resource.actions.configs=resource-actions/default.xml
```

The questions is - why do I have nothing in control panel besides default actions life "ADD_TO_PAGE", etc? What am I doing wrong?

UPD:
This varient doesn't work too. =(

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE resource-action-mapping PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Resource Action Mapping 7.0.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-resource-action-mapping_7_0_0.dtd">

<resource-action-mapping>

<model-resource>
        <model-name>mypackage.web.portlet.MyPortlet</model-name>
    <portlet-ref>
        <portlet-name>mypackage_web_portlet_MyPortlet</portlet-name>
    </portlet-ref>
    <root>true</root>
    <weight>1</weight>
    <permissions>
        <supports>
            <action-key>VIEW_TEST</action-key>
        </supports>
        <site-member-defaults>
            <action-key>SUBSCRIBE_TEST</action-key>
        </site-member-defaults>
        <guest-defaults />
        <guest-unsupported>
            <action-key>ADD_ENTRY_TEST</action-key>
            <action-key>PERMISSIONS_TEST</action-key>
            <action-key>SUBSCRIBE_TEST</action-key>
        </guest-unsupported>
    </permissions>
</model-resource>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `<model-resource>` block rather than `<portlet-resource>`: Portlet-Resource is handled by Liferay (and uses the predefined vocabulary) while your portlet or service introduces its own datatypes, on which you can define your own permissions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've updated my question. I've already tried to use `<model-resource>` and it's doesn't work.

Could you tell me smth like step-by-step sequence of actions? I think I just miss something